# Want to add text field values to database using jQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I want to insert text field values to database using javascript jQuery AJAX call to C# server method. Problem is that AJAX call run successfully but C# is not updating the database. What could be the reason? Please reply soon. 
ASP code is giving below:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dbTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="dbTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

         function SaveOnClick() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "dbTest.aspx/SaveData",
                 data: "{'CustomerName': '" + $('#txtCustomerName').val() + "', 'CustomerPhoneNumber': '" + $('#txtCustomerPhoneNumber').val() + "', 'ColorID': '" + $('#txtColorID').val() + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(result, txtstatus) {
                     alert(txtstatus);
                 },
                 error: function(result) {
                     alert("jQuery Error:" + result.statusText);
                 }
             });
         }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Customers" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="CustomerDetails">
    </div>
    <table border="0">
<tr>
 <td align="right"><strong>Customer Name:</strong></td>
 <td align="left">
  <asp:TextBox id="txtCustomerName" maxlength="50" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="right"><strong>Customer Phone Number:</strong></td>
 <td align="left">
  <asp:TextBox id="txtCustomerPhoneNumber" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="right"><strong>Color ID:</strong></td>
 <td align="left">
  <asp:TextBox id="txtColorId" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="SaveOnClick()" value="click me"/>

<asp:Panel id="pnlConfirm" runat="server">
 <h2>Thanks for submitting your information to us!</h2>

</asp:Panel>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class dbTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlConfirm.Visible = false;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SaveData(string CustomerName, string CustomerPhoneNumber, string ColorID)
    {
        string Server = "al2c06";
        string Username = "app_Testing";
        string Password = "jsjsdj";
        string Database = "AmbreenTest";

        string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Server + ";";
        ConnectionString += "User ID=" + Username + ";";
        ConnectionString += "Password=" + Password + ";";
        ConnectionString += "Initial Catalog=" + Database;
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customer_Order(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, colorID)";
        query += "VALUES (";
        query += "'" + CustomerName+ "'";
        query += ",";
        query += "'" + CustomerPhoneNumber + "'";
        query += ",";
        query += "'" + ColorID+ "'";
        query += ")";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
        //lblSQL.Text = query;
        //pnlConfirm.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What doesn't work ? Does your SaveData method get run ? Is it hooked up correctly to be run for the URL you are pointing to ? It seems you might be mixing an ASP .NET page and a web service. If it is being run, attach a debugger and identify the line of code, where it fails, and whether an exception is thrown. Post the details here, and we will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My savedata get run. because alert box in the success handler of ajax call is showing up. but when i check data in the managemennt studio, it doesnt update. table dont have those values. this is the problem.

Comment: may be the problem is with my query

Answer (score 0):

Fix your jQuery selector first, they are case sensitive. Change `$('#txtColorID').val()` to `$('#txtColorId').val()`.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't get the posted values. That is the problem.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void SaveData(string CustomerName, string CustomerPhoneNumber, string ColorID)
    {
        string Server = "al2c06";
        string Username = "app_AmbreenTesting";
        string Password = "testing";
        string Database = "AmbreenTesting";

        string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Server + ";";
        ConnectionString += "User ID=" + Username + ";";
        ConnectionString += "Password=" + Password + ";";
        ConnectionString += "Initial Catalog=" + Database;
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customer_Order(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, colorID)";
        query += "VALUES (";
        query += "'" + Request.Form["CustomerName"].ToString()+ "'";
        query += ",";
        query += "'" + Request.Form["CustomerPhoneNumber"].ToString() + "'";
        query += ",";
        query += "'" + Request.Form["ColorID"].ToString()+ "'";
        query += ")";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        //lblSQL.Text = query;
        //pnlConfirm.Visible = true;
    }
```

HTH

Comment: The posted values are the parameters to his method, but as I comment, I am not sure how it is hooked up to be run, if it is at all.
Anyways, this code will fail, because you are in a static Context, so you can't access ´Request´.

Comment: Oh ya you are right...I usually have a web method and get the information from Request.Form. By the way what is the error??

Comment: I tried ur method and made my web method non-static to use Request.Form but then jquery error occur

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```